# html fieldset inner height

Tags: javascript, css, fieldset

I have a fieldset with several divs inside, of which only one is displayed at a time. I want the fieldset to always keep its height, even when the visibility of its contents changes. So I set the fieldset.style.minHeight to the maximum of the offsetHeight of all possible content parts. But this doesn't take into account that the minHeight is the height of the outside and not the client part of the fieldset. So I tried to add the difference between the offsetHeight and the clientHeight of the fieldset. But this is not the correct value (it is only 2 px in my case).

So the question is: how to set the minHeight of a fieldset so that there is egnough space for a child with a given height. (I am using no borders, margins or padding, I am looking for a pure JavaScript solution)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhmhm71L/5)

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <fieldset id="fs">
        <legend>Status</legend> 
        <span id="id1" style="display: block;">Short text.</span>
        <span id="id2" style="display: block;">Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. Some longer text. </span>
    </fieldset>
    <input type=submit value="toggle" onclick="toggle()" />
</body>

function onLoad() {
    var fs = document.getElementById("fs");
    var span1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var span2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    fs.style.minHeight = Math.max(span1.offsetHeight, span2.offsetHeight).toString() + "px";
    span1.style.display = "block";
    span2.style.display = "none";
}

function toggle() {
    var span1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var span2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    if (span1.style.display == "block") {
        span1.style.display = "none";
        span2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        span1.style.display = "block";
        span2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: I am working on it, I never made one, so it takes some time ...

Comment: Finally got the jsfiddle done: http://jsfiddle.net/zhmhm71L/5/

Comment: The question is still a little confusing - looking at your JSFiddle - You already achieve what has been asked - setting the minHeight style property of the Fieldset equal to the height of the highest child element in it. Am I missing something ? - Should the value be 54px ? (which is the height of the current greatest child element height)

Comment: It is not static, I don't know the spans in advance, so I must derive the height of the fieldset somehow from the highest span, but of course not waste space by choosing some arbitrary extra offset. In my browser, when I ckick "toggle" the fieldset size changes, which I don't want. It seems to be egnough adding twice the fontsize of the fieldset, but that is not logical.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ps92wynp/

```
#fs {
    min-height:70px !important;
}
```

Comment: It does not make a difference. What is the idea?

Answer (score 0):

The fieldset clientHeight will never be the size of the largest child's `offsetHeight`. You mentioned a 2px difference, and it makes sense adding the minimum height to the maximum height - guaranteeing enough space for all children elements.

I see where you got the 2px difference - Inspecting the fieldset. with a `min-height` set at `54px` - the Actual height of the Fieldset was `90px`. Changing the `min-height` to the formulae answered below - The height was `92px` when the `min-height` was set to `72px`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ps92wynp/7/

```
function onLoad() {
    var fs = document.getElementById("fs");
    var span1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var span2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    fs.style.minHeight = (Math.max(span1.offsetHeight, span2.offsetHeight) + Math.min(span1.offsetHeight, span2.offsetHeight)) .toString() + "px"; //72px in your example.
    span1.style.display = "block";
    span2.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: No, both spans could be large (in fact I have many), it would waste too much space.